# Checking collection data in where clause oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections

Need to add condition in where clause based on collection values.
    `create or replace type item_type force as object
    (
    key number(3),
    value varchar2(20)
    )

    create or replace type item_coll force as table of item_type

    create or replace type req_type force as object
    (
    rule varchar2(20),
    items item_coll
    )`


    `procedure sample( in_a IN req_type, out_b OUT ret_coll)
     as
     select * bulk collect into out_b
     from tab_test a
     where a.rule= in_a.rule;`


    Example:
    `Input string : req_type('aaa',item_coll(item_type(1,'A'),item_type(2,'B'),item_type(3,'C')));`


    Final query should be like,
    `Select * bulk collect into out_b
    from tab_test a
    where a.rule= in_a.rule
          and ((a.key = 1 and a.value = 'A') OR
          (a.key = 2 and a.value = 'B') OR
          (a.key = 3 and a.value = 'C'))`

Could anyone please suggest solution on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there are the other ways, but this is something what worked for me:

```
select item_type(a.key, a.value)
  bulk collect into out_b
  from tab_test a
  where in_a.rule = a.rule 
    and (a.key, a.value) in (select key, value from table(in_a.items));
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=44b05e9053f15cf2614f2c50ffc5a1b5)</sup>**

Answer (score 0):

```
select item_type(a.key, a.value)
   bulk collect into out_b
   from tab_test a
   where in_a.rule = a.rule 
   and exists (select 'x' 
                  from table(in_a.items) i
                  where a.key = i.key
                  and a.value = i.key);
```